# Look inside a header file in C

Tags: c, header

I am learning C but how do I look inside of the header file. So in Python you would do help(str) to see all the functions part of class string. What is the equivalent of that in C?

Comment: Open the header file in an editor?

Comment: for `stdio.h` for instance type `vi /usr/include/stdio.h` in terminal to see the content of the header !!

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the C standard library header files on [Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an equivalent. You pray that the developer left nice comments in the `.h` and read it directly.

Comment: Surely you wouldn't pay for a library that *Wasn't* nicely documented!

Comment: I doubt you pay for poorly commented libraries, but your coworkers will gladly write them for you.